# How to trigger blockui from c#?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm looking for a way to trigger BlockUI from the code behind. I have server-side validations and I would not want the BlockUI to fire unless the server validations are complete.

Here's my button :

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnSave" runat="server" OnClick="BtnSaveUpdate_Click" Text="Save"  CausesValidation="true"></asp:Button>
```

Code behind:

This is what I tried doing but this doesn't work:

```
protected void BtnSaveUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "blockui", " $.blockUI({  message: 'Saving Record...'  });", true);
                // remaining code...
             }
        }
```

This is my original javascript code which fires before server validation:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#BtnSave').click(function () {

                $.blockUI({
                    message: 'Saving Record...'
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: @LucasSouza Yes, but what about Server-side validation ?

Comment: What about a WebMethod?

Comment: @LucasSouza  You mean to do the server validations from a WebMethod? If so, I think it would be difficult because I can't have access to the Page Controls from a web method as far as I understand.